# How to load uisplit viewcontroller on button click

Tags: iphone, ios

i am new to iPhone development.

How to load a page having uisplitview controller on button click

Please help

Answer (score 0):

some points:

1. UISplitView controllers are to be used exclusively on iPad devices. "Split view controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception." in [Apple developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISplitViewController)
2. UISplitView controllers must be the root controllers. You may use UINavigationController and create a segue from one UIViewController to another using the storyboard (press the control key and mouse click the UIViewController to start the segue with and release the mouse button on top of the destination UIViewController). On a button click event use the method `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NameOfSegue" sender:self];` (UIViewController method). you can change the name of the segue in the storyboard when you press the segue (you will see the identifier field on the properties section on the right)

Hope this helps.